# Aligning two navigation bars of different widths with margin auto? CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I am trying to align a 2nd navigation bar that is shorter than the original navigation bar, to meet the right hand side of the original. Probably doesn't make much sense so here is an image to help:
http://i49.tinypic.com/nohno7.jpg

The CSS for top navigation bar is :

```
#nav { width:940px; height:40px; margin:0 auto; padding:0; font-size:105%; background:url(../images/bg-nav.png) 0 0 repeat-x; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0 0 3px #ccc; }
```

The CSS for the 2nd navigation bar is :

```
#nav2 { width:547px; height:40px; margin:1px auto; padding:0; font-size:105%; background:url(../images/bg-nav.png) 0 0 repeat-x; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0 0 3px #ccc; }
```

If anyone can help point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float:right` might solve your question for the 2nd nav bar?

EDIT: I guess I've got what your page look likes: your nav bars are just directly inside the `body` tag. So let's do some small changes:

1. Add a div holding your two nav bars. Let's call it `nav-bar`.
    `<div id="nav-bar"><!--1st nav--><!--2nd nav--></div>`
2. Add some css:
   `#nav-bar {width:940px;height:80px; margin:0 auto; padding:0;}`
   `#nav2 {float:right;}`

And complete the rest of the css for nav2
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this just throws the 2nd nav bar to the far right hand side of the page against the scroller :(

Comment: Thanks for the help. Managed to fix it in the end by playing around.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-container2 { width:940px; margin:auto; height:30px;}
#nav2 { width:547px; height:40px; float:right; margin:1px 0 0 0; font-size:105%; background:url(../images/bg-nav.png) 0 0 repeat-x; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0 0 3px #ccc; }
```